# Add .live or .on to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JavaScript that pulls how many items I have in my cart and places it in span.cartTotal for better styling.  I need the code to work so it pulls the information instantly and I don't have to refresh my page to see the update. I assume the code would require either jquery .live or .on to be added. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

```
$(function(){         
    if ($('#catCartSummary .cartSummaryItem').html() != 'Shopping cart is empty.') {
         var summary = $('#catCartSummary .cartSummaryItem').text().split(" ");
         var total = summary[0];
      $('span.cartTotal').html(total);
    }else{
      $('span.cartTotal').html("0");
    }
});
```

More info: My add to cart class is .productSubmitInput

I pull the info from this code below which is dynamically created. This cart total updates automatically in cartSummaryItem. I just need my new styled total to update from it when someone adds to cart. I tried the below suggestions but they didn't seem to work. I could be just adding something wrong.

```
<td class="cartSummaryItem">
1 item(s), Total: $10.95 
</td>
```

Comment: Put your code inside whatever event modifies the number of items in the cart instead of the doc.ready which only executes once when the DOM is....ready.

Comment: You could wrap that in a named function and call it on the click event of any "Add to Cart" buttons, since it would only be triggered by user interaction.

Comment: What does not work with your code? Or is the html of the `.cartSummaryItems` updated dynamically somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the comments said, basically

also - use .on not .live, as .live is deprecated

Something like this:

```
function updateTotals() {
 if ($('#catCartSummary .cartSummaryItem').html() != 'Shopping cart is empty.') {
         var summary = $('#catCartSummary .cartSummaryItem').text().split(" ");
         var total = summary[0];
      $('span.cartTotal').html(total);
    }else{
      $('span.cartTotal').html("0");
    }
}

$(function(){
  updateTotals(); // <-- initial load update

  $('some_selector').on('click',function(){

    // do stuff like adding items to cart or w/e...

    updateTotals();

  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Evan, I updated the info above. What changes would I make to your script? Thanks

Comment: just use your .productSubmitInput as the selector

Comment: Hi Evan, I am getting a syntax error on the first line. function() updateTotals() {

Comment: This works for the click function but when the page loads it does not show the value of whats in the cart until I click add to cart. Any thoughts?

Comment: If I leave my old code as well it works. But that does not seem like a proper solution.

Comment: just call the function in the document.ready function, I've edited the answer to show this. Also - if this is helpful, please select the "checkmark" and give an upvote :)